# How can I hide/remove meta line "Item Details:" from Order Line Items in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, invoice

I want to hide / remove the following highlighted line (row) from all orders (past and current).
[image]

Follow is the code which is displayed on browser console.
[image]

It's just creating duplicate variation entries everywhere (even invoices) which I don't require. Just so you know, I'm using OpenPOS plugin.

Answer (score 0):

put this to your theme/functions.php to hide that

```html
 add_filter('woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta',function($meta){
     $meta[] = 'op_item_details';
     return $meta;
 },101,1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working on dashboard, however it's not reflecting on PDF Invoice.

Dashboard : https://i.postimg.cc/VNS2WgKj/screenshot-2023-04-19-10-46-09.png
PDF Invoice : https://i.postimg.cc/85M3q5Qc/Screenshot-2023-04-19-10-42-57-AM.png

Comment: it should check the pdf invouce you are using to ignore display on it .

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve it by first, looping through each piece of formatted meta data for the order item using:
`foreach ( $formatted_meta as $key => $meta )`

Then, checked if the meta key is 'op_item_details' or not (which we want to remove):
`if ( 'op_item_details' === $meta->key )`

Afterwards, we remove the **op_item_details** meta from the array : `unset( $formatted_meta[ $key ] )`

And finally, we return the modified array without the 'op_item_details' meta :
`return $formatted_meta;`